# Can not pass data(json) from an event handler to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple **eventHandler** in which a have a simple function with a **json** object. When a **click** event occurs I want to pass this json object data to that function to alert a message.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnClick').on({                   
            click: function (event) {                   
                sayHello();
            },
            firstName: 'Raihan'
        });
        function sayHello(event)
        {
            alert('Yo ' + event.data.firstName);                
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In an environment that's all javascript.. you want to convert an object to a transfer language... WHY???  That's really a bad idea.  Javascript and JSON are NOT the same.  You should consider removing JSON from the question all together.

Comment: Here firstName is just for testing purpose. the actual data will be a form collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnClick').on({                   
        click: function (event) {
            event.data = {firstName: 'Raihan' };
            sayHello(event);
        }
    });
    function sayHello(event)
    {
        alert('Yo ' + event.data.firstName + "\r\n\r\n" + " Event data: " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));                
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnClick">ClickMe</button>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qehm3svy/8/

Comment: Check out the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qehm3svy/4/, this is close to what you need I think!

Comment: the sayHello function is only receiving data here but i need it to receive the whole event

Comment: I've updated the answer to include event data! This is in the code snippet!

Comment: Cool :) No problem!

Comment: Can you please explain why i need that :  " Event data: " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4)

Comment: You don't at all, it's just for the purposes of the demo! You can simply access the properties of the event in the sayHello function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the "event" argument to you sayhello function. Below is the code please try this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnClick').on({                   
            click: function (event) {                   
                sayHello(event);
            },
            firstName: 'Raihan'
        });
        function sayHello(event)
        {
            alert('Yo ' + event.data.firstName);                
        }
    });
</script>
```